# Windows 8 Secondary Live Tile not updating using local notification queue

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, tiles

I am trying to implement more than two secondary live tiles in my application. I have followed this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178) to create secondary tiles using pin-to-start buttons on the app bar. I am updating the secondary tiles using the NotificationExtensions Library present. Now, I am facing a problem wherein, I am trying to locally update each of my live tiles using the notification queue, but the entire behavior of the updates is erratic at best. Only one of the 3 tiles is updated continuously (there is no fixed tile that is successfully updated) while the rest are updated just once and then stop at that. I am afraid this has something to do with the notifications not being properly queued but I have no idea where I am going wrong. Initially, all my secondary tile creation and their respective notifying logic were in separate code-behinds. I even tried to club them into a single page but it still gives the same result. I am using the following code to create the notification tile content:

```
            ITileWideText04 tileContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWideText04();
            tileContent.TextBodyWrap.Text = "1 secondary tile from NotificationsExtensions!";

            ITileSquareText04 squareContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquareText04();
            squareContent.TextBodyWrap.Text = "1secondary tile from NotificationExtensions!";
            tileContent.SquareContent = squareContent;


            ITileWideText04 tileContent2 = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWideText04();
            tileContent2.TextBodyWrap.Text = "2c secondary tile from NotificationsExtensions!";

            ITileSquareText04 squareContent2 = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquareText04();
            squareContent2.TextBodyWrap.Text = "2 secondary tile from NotificationExtensions!";
            tileContent2.SquareContent = squareContent;

            var tile1 = tileContent.CreateNotification();
            tile1.Tag = "a";
            var tile2 = tileContent2.CreateNotification();
            tile2.Tag = "b";
```

and then updating the tiles like so:
                                       TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(Constants.ProfileAppTile).EnableNotificationQueue(true);
           TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(Constants.ProfileAppTile).Update(tile1);
                TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(Constants.ProfileAppTile).Update(tile2);

And so on for the rest of the secondary tiles.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  What may be happening is that it is getting a new updater for you each time on these lines of code that you reference, and enabling the notification queue is only happening on the first one:

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(Constants.ProfileAppTile).EnableNotificationQueue(true); 
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(Constants.ProfileAppTile).Update(tile1);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(Constants.ProfileAppTile).Update(tile2);
```

In your bottom code snippet, can you instead try something like this?

```
var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(Constants.ProfileAppTile);
updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true); 
updater.Update(tile1); 
updater.Update(tile2);
```

In addition, these articles contain sample code that works properly, with secondary tiles and live tiles, which you are welcome to borrow from:
[Real-World Secondary Tiles: Top Three Tips for Working with Secondary Tiles in Windows 8 Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/19/real-world-secondary-tiles-top-three-tips-for-working-with-secondary-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx)
[Real-World Live Tiles: Working with Live Tiles in Windows 8 Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/20/real-world-live-tiles-working-with-live-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx)

Comment: Hi Jennifer, Thanks for the reply. I tried the above workaround but still facing the same issue. Also, I had gone through the above articles and although your article is fantastic to provide local notifications on demand, it does not have a sample for enabling local notifications in queue. I was wondering if probably there is a sample out there that I have missed?

Comment: Have you looked at this sample?  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148